# Display remote content (html) inside PhoneGap application

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I am writing an HTML / JS application and plan to submit to the iPhone store after compiling with PhonegGap.

My question is can the application make an ajax call to a remote server and display HTML code returned by that call?  I know this is technically possible but am wondering if this is allowed by Apple?

Does anyone have any direct experience with this?  Would love to hear from someone that either has an app in the app-store that does this or someone that has had an application rejected for something along these lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apple guidelines state that the only downloaded code allowed to be executed in an application is javascript/webkit. HTML certainly falls into that category.